# How to combine images with the same dimensions in a grid?

Tags: image-processing

I have the following images, both 480 x 270 pixels:

[image: AquaSilk (Zangief) vs EMP EvilRahsaan (Blanka) - capture 1]

[image: AquaSilk (Zangief) vs EMP EvilRahsaan (Gen) - capture 2]

I'd like to stitch them side by side in a 960 x 270 pixel image like so (scaled down):

[image: images side-by-side]

So far, I've been using [`GraphicsGrid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsGrid.html) to try to achieve this:

```
c1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SRcD.png"];
c2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL8id.png"];
(* Frame parameter set here to emphasize next point. *)
g = GraphicsGrid[{{c1, c2}}, Frame -> True]
```

But there's padding between the images:

[image: GraphicsGrid call with c1 and c2]

Additionally, it's scaled incorrectly, as [`ImageDimensions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageDimensions.html) shows:

```
ImageDimensions@g

(* Expect {960, 540} *)
{360, 180}
```

I can use the `ImageSize` parameter to explicitly set the size of the output image, but that just reproduces the above result to scale.

How can combine the images side-by-side without scaling or padding?

Comment: My proxy/firewall won't let me `Import` the pictures, but isn't this a job for `ImagePadding->None`?

Comment: @Verbeia `ImagePadding -> None` actually masks the entire image with a thick white border all around, cropping the images in half with the parts along the vertical center being exposed.

Comment: Try `Grid` instead of `GraphicsGrid`. I'm at work now so I can't really pursue this now, but `GraphicsGrid` enforces equal column widths, so this might be causing a problem. `ImageAssemble` is the neatest solution, but there are others.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you're looking for is `ImageAssemble`:

```
c1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SRcD.png"];
c2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL8id.png"];
ImageAssemble[{c1, c2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

It can also assemble vertically and horizontally:

```
ImageAssemble[{{c1, c1}, {c2, c2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

Comment: As well as fleshing out the answer, I'm actually doing the 4x4, but displaying the NxN case is the best answer overall.

Answer (score 7):

Incidentally, `ImageDimensions` on `GraphicsGrid` is behaving correctly.  `GraphicsGrid` is generating an object with head `Graphics`, with a default width of 360 points, and the contents scaled down to fit. `ImageDimensions` then creates a bitmap version of the graphic, maintaining the size on screen, and returns the dimensions for that.