# Tuning ParallelMap when IO and computationally bound

Tags: image-processing, parallelization

I'm currently doing work on processing a number of images taken frame-by-frame from a video.  As a result, I have a directory of around 16K PNG images that at most ~300K.

That said, I have a routine, `analyze` which I map in the following way:

```
analyse /@ FileNames[ "captures\\*.png" , nbDir];
```

[`analyse` is a `Module` with calls to a number of image-processing functions that are computationally bound](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/detecting-a-fixed-template-image-out-of-a-semi-constant-frame-of-video):

- `ColorSeparate`
- `Binarize`
- `ImageCorrelate`
- `ColorNegate`
- `ColorConvert`
- `BitCounts`
- Possibly some mask operations using `ImageAdd`, `ImageMultiply` and `Dilation`
- [Assembling the images using `ImageAssemble`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/246/108)

That said, I'm heavily computationally bound for the the process I perform on each image, but also heavily disk/IO bound because there are so many images.

To that end, I've started using [`ParallelMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelMap.html) like so:

```
ParallelMap[analyse, FileNames["captures\\*.png" , nbDir]];
```

However, I know of the `Method` parameter which allows one to specify just *how much* parallelization should take place in `ParallelMap`.

My gut instinct here is to go with the `CoarsestGrained` option for the `Method` parameter but I can't really put together why the approach would be valid (or invalid, if it were not).

For this situation, what approach can I take to tune this call to `ParallelMap` in order to get the best performance (to be specific, I'd like it to be done as soon as possible, with a disregard for resource consumption if sacrifices are to be made).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case, you would want to favor `Method->FinestGrained`, not `Method->CoarsestGrained`.

`FinestGrained` is more useful when the workload has items that may take a very long time to process, or which may have wildly varying computation times.

`CoarsestGrained` is useful when the workload consists of many fast, easy to compute items. You don't want to have heavy synchronization and dispatch when you're adding 1 to 10^10 numbers, do you?

I'll add some real examples shortly. But in general:

- `FinestGrained`: Computation bound or varying completion time
- `CoarsestGrained`: Fast computations. Really fast ones. Communication is expensive so you want to limit it.

You can really view it the two options as tradeoffs between TComm (cost of communication) vs TComp (cost of computation. In other words:

```
If[TComm > TComp,
    Method->"CoarsestGrained",
    Method->"FinestGraned"]
```

---

If you want some more control over the grain, you can utilize `Method->ItemsPerEvaluation->n`. In this case, we hand out n items to each kernel when they come for work. You can use this to further tweak how fine Mathematica grains your calculations.

As a note, the default option of `Method->Automatic` (which is implicit any time you use `Parallel*`) performs load balancing we may be expensive to perform if your workload is better suited to fine or coarse grained.

Remember though -- Always measure!

Comment: I agree, always measure; still at the point where I'm trying to figure this all out. =)

Comment: @casperOne: I'll give you examples soon - I promise!

Comment: It's turning out to be extremely difficult to find examples where you would prefer finest grained over coarsest grained..

Comment: In this case or in general?

Comment: In general. I'm trying all kinds of cases and it's turning out that neither makes a huge difference. I'm finding all the cases where Mathematica does fine using any of the methods.

Comment: That would mean the answer would change quite substantially, no?

Comment: @casperOne: yes. The explanation above holds in general. many of the cases I described above are from personal experience with some simulations I've run.  Most are too complicated to post here unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

As another approach, you might want to consider using `ParallelSubmit` and `WaitAll` or `WaitNext` for this task:

```
tasks = Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, i^2], {i, 100}];

WaitAll[tasks]
```

which gives `{1, 4, 9, ..., 10000}`

Comment: Is this applicable to Mike's question on [asynchronous evaluation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/238/52)? (I'm out of upvotes.)

Comment: Do I have to worry about overloading a queue?  We're talking submitting tens of thousands of items to be process here, and I don't necessarily need to wait (although that's good to know), for now, I just need to know when done.