# Tile image on specific location without space between them

Tags: graphics, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to combine images with the same dimensions in a grid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246/how-to-combine-images-with-the-same-dimensions-in-a-grid)

I would like to arrange images without any space between their edges as each piece is made to connect with others.

The images should not necessarily be merged but simply tiled.

My ultimate purpose is to use a Manipulate to generate different arrangements.

So, how can I place those images in a coordinate system so I can define 9 positions and assign those locations to the images without any space between them ?

Below my attempt using Grid and 2 example of the desired Output once I figure this out. Those composition were generated using Java Scripts.

**EDIT** :

The problem with `Grid` or `ImageAssemble` is they would not allow for "empty slots", which is an option I would like to have as shown in the last image for example.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the results you want differ in any way from this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/246/52)?

Comment: @rcollyer, I am having trouble to express it, but what I need is to be able to assign positions from 1 to 9 as I will implement some rules about the "neighborhood". I would group the elements by their attributes : Color or B&White for example and say for example that no B&W should be close to a color one. So i am looking for the best system that will enable me that. I am happy to merge or delete if you think they are redundant.

Comment: So what you need is code to organize the images, not necessarily merge them together, correct?

Comment: @rcollyer, Yes. The underlying subject is I tried to create sets of elements that can be re arranged in many way. I want to use mathematica to generate and select a lot of combination. While now they are all tiled together I might want to have empty locations at some point.

Comment: @rcollyer, maybe this will help http://www.laeh500.com/LAEH/Meet_Arto.html

Comment: I'm on a slow network today, so I won't be able to watch it easily. I'd suggest you update your question with the additional requirements, and point out that you have cases where the other question won't work (and what they are). It has 3 close votes (1 mine - can't rescind), but with the new info, I probably will be the first to vote for reopening, if it is closed.

Comment: I updated my answer to allow for empty slots.

Answer (score 6):

One can in fact use the (once documented) third argument of `Rectangle[]` to tile images. Here's an example I cooked up:

```
imgs = {ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Clock"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Elaine"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "JellyBeans"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Peppers"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Splash"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tiffany"}], 
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "U2"}]};

mat = Partition[RandomSample[Range[9]], 3];
Graphics[Table[Rectangle[{j, k}, {j + 1, k + 1}, imgs[[mat[[j + 1, k + 1]]]]],
               {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}]]
```

[image: random images]

The idea is that, you have nine images to distribute on a 3×3 grid; you thus partition some permutation of the numbers $1$ to $9$ in groups of three (that is, `mat`), have the indices of `Table[]` map to a corresponding entry of `mat`, and then that entry of `mat` has a corresponding index in the list `imgs`. The extension to any number of images to be arranged in a grid should be straightforward.

Comment: Does this allow for empty slots in the array?

Comment: Just use a  conditional as needed: `If[j == 2 && k == 1, (* then *) {White, Rectangle[{j, k}, {j + 1, k + 1}]}, (* else *) Rectangle[{j, k}, {j + 1, k + 1}, imgs[[mat[[j + 1, k + 1]]]]]]`

Comment: @J.M., Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

If your images are the same size, a quick and dirty hack is using `ImageAssemble` in place of `Grid`.  (I used that before several times.)

You can generate "empty slots" for use with `ImageAssemble` like this:  `Rasterize[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[existingImage]], "Image"]`.  Adjust the required image size as needed.

Otherwise the `Grid` option to use should be `Spacings`, but I always have some trouble with that:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Regarding importing images, you can consider building on the following simpler code:

```
ImageResize[#, 256] & /@ Import /@ FileNames["B*.png"]
```

Comment: beat me to it by 2 seconds

Comment: @Heike There's still the question of doing this properly (no gaps) with `Grid` though ...

Comment: Setting `Spacings->{0,0}` works on my system.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Thank You ! Could you explain me the use of "*" in the importing function ?

Comment: @500 `FileNames["B*.png"]` will give you all files start with a `B` and end in `.png` in the current directory.  The keyword to google for is [wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#Files_and_directories).

Comment: @Szabolcs, Thank You !

Comment: @Szabolcs, despite having put the images in the same directory, FileNames["B*.png"] return an empty list for me :-)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, when working at magnification 200% I get no gaps in `Grid` using `Spacing -> {0, 0}`.  You could therefore `Rasterize` and `ImageResize` from there as needed.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wizard, thank you !