# How to work around Column cutting off a pixel row from images?

Tags: front-end, formatting

I have a problem where `Column` will occasionally cut off a single pixel from the top of images.

To reproduce the problem, evaluate this:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dEty.png"]
Column[{"text", Image[image, Magnification -> 1], "text"}]
```

The output I get looks like this in the front end:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that in `Out[2]` a single pixel wide row is cut off from the top of the image.  It does not occur with all images, but it does with this particular one.

**How can I work around this problem?**  This is on Win7.  Can you reproduce on other platforms?

I need this for the [image uploader palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes) (`` SOUploader`uploadWithPreview[] `` function to be specific).

---

It is interesting to note that if I wrap the image in a `Pane`, and set a pane-size explicitly (as in the original code of the palette), whether the row is cut off depends on whether the size is even or odd (I suspect a rounding issue):

Try this and notice that the cropping happens for even `k` only:

```
Table[
 Column[{"text", 
   Pane[Image[image, Magnification -> 1], 
    ImageDimensions[image] + {0, k}], "text"}],
 {k, 0, 5}
 ]
```

Comment: Possibly related:  The gaps in the `Grid` here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/753/12

Comment: Everything's fine in my frontend, http://stupidname.org/files/temp/temp_2012_01/sshot_2012-01-26_12:59:18.png

Comment: @David Probably Windows-only.

Comment: seems to work fine on os x as well. If it's just for uploading, can't you pad the image with one pixel using `ImagePad`?

Comment: Playing with `Magnification`, the cropping is eliminated if you use `Image[image, Magnification -> 1.000001]` or higher magnification. An alternative is adding `1` or more to the vertical range in both `PlotRange` and `ImageSize` in the rasterized image like so: `Graphics[Raster@Reverse@ImageData[image], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, ImageDimensions[image][[1]]}, {0, 
    1 + ImageDimensions[image][[2]]}}, 
 ImageSize -> {{0, ImageDimensions[image][[1]]}, {0, 
    1 + ImageDimensions[image][[2]]}}]`. All this on Windows Vista.

Comment: @kguler Thanks!  I'll try the magnification trick first, let's see if it distorts the image at all.  I don't want to convert to Raster if I don't have to.  Yes, it's a hack, but if it works, it should be an answer, not a comment.  This is a practical problem, and I just want a solution.

Comment: @kguler It seems even if I set a higher magnification, things are randomly cropped by a pixel as I click in different places in the front end.  It's a really annoying bug.  I already had to increase the `Panel` size by a pixel to work around a similar bug

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be due to a small rounding issue on Windows.

Here is a test Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
 matrix = ArrayFlatten[Table[DiamondMatrix[size], {x}, {y}]];
 image = Image[matrix /. {0 -> {0, 0, 0}, 1 -> {255, 255, 255}},
  "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True];
 Column[{"test", Image[image, Magnification -> 1], "test"}],
 {size, 1, 20, 1},
 {x, 1, 20, 1},
 {y, 1, 20, 1}
]
```

Under certain settings the top row of pixels in the image is cut off:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot reproduce the error I can only guess. Maybe setting the [`Spacings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Spacings.html) option for `Column` helps? This is what `Spacing -> 0` looks like:

[image]

You can see the gray dividers above the image appearing and then not making it to the middle because of the overlap. Increasing spacing solves this problem, here's `Spacing -> 1`:

[image]

The lines are now visible, and nothing is clipped.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately `Spacings` doesn't change the incorrect rounding behaviour (and the cropping).