# How to anchor a Pane's scroll position to the bottom?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, interface

Suppose I have a `Pane` containing some dynamic text, for example that is being updated by a logging function.

```
Pane[Dynamic[logText],
  Scrollbars -> {False, True},
  ImageSize -> {Full, 200},
  ScrollPosition -> {0, 10000000}]
```

I want this pane to remain scrolled to the bottom so that I can always see the last line of text. I tried setting `ScrollPosition -> {0, Infinity}` (or to `{0, Full}`, or to `{0, All}`), which would be a possible interface to achieve this, but neither of these work.

Comment: Why do you use the `Print` function?

Comment: Good question!  I don't think it's necessary. Possibly this is a holdover from when I was outputting this in the code that was doing the calculation.

Answer (score 8):

I was busy exploring this problem on my own for some time now, and was not satisfied with any of the answers. They both work for some extent, but, concerning Szabolcs's answer, I would like to avoid image-processing and in case of Mr.Wizard's answer there are slight problems with it during startup (see comments) and it breaks down when the scroll position is defined as a dynamic variable itself. Thus I set out to find a better solution.

### The problem

First, I want to clearly state the problem (at least what my problem was originally): given a `Pane` that listens to a dynamic variable `text`, I have to update it such that whenever `text` changes by a controller (e.g. a button), the `Pane` is automatically scrolled down to the actual end of content. But I also want to keep both the manipulable scrollbar of the `Pane` **and** the possibility to manipulate the vertical scroll position `pos` via another external controler (e.g. a slider). Thus the resulting `Pane` **must be updated differently**, depending on whether `text` or `pos` triggers an update.

I present two solutions, the second one being the better one in my opinion. For both cases, I exploit the fact that if the initial vertical scroll position value (`pos`) is set large enough, *Mathematica* automatically finds and sets the scroll position to the end of content.

### 1. Injecting code in the external controller

The simpler method is to separate the different updates by assigning them to the external controllers. Here, a button is provided that updates `text` externally (external to the dynamic `Pane` object), but it also directly redraws the `Pane` to find the end-of-content position.

```
pos = 1000; (* vertical scroll position *) 
c = 5; (* text update counter *)
text = "1\n2\n3333333333333333\n44";

(* note that this button explicitly contains the update[] code *)
Button["Update text", cc = c++; text = text <> "\n" <> 
   StringJoin@Table[ToString@cc, {RandomInteger@{1, 15}}] <> "<"; pane = update[]]
update[] := (
   pos = pos + 1000; 
   Framed@Pane[Dynamic@text, ImageSize -> {120, 60}, 
     Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
     ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[{0, pos}, (pos = Last@#) &]]
  );

pane = update[]; (* initialize Pane *)
{Dynamic@pane, Dynamic@pos}
```

Note that updating `text` via the button or via the scrollbar correctly updates `pane` and `pos`. The only problem here is that one has to manually put the `pane = update[]` code into the controller, which is unwanted (at least in my case), as one only wants to change `text` via the button.

### 2. Separating updates via selective triggers

The beautiful [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21600/89) by @Leonid provides a method to selectively separate different update methods of a dynamic expression depending on which "parent" variable triggers an update.

```
SetAttributes[makeTrigger, HoldAll];
makeTrigger[res_, var_, updateCode_] := Module[{varOld = var, trigger}, 
   trigger /; varOld =!= var := (varOld = var; res = updateCode); 
   trigger];

pos = 1000;
c = 5;
text = "1\n2\n3333333333333333\n44";
size = {120, 60};

Button["Update text", cc = c++; text = text <> "\n" <> 
   StringJoin@Table[ToString@cc, {RandomInteger@{1, 15}}] <> "<";]
Row@{"Update pos: ", Slider[Dynamic@pos, {0, 200}]}
update[] := Framed@Pane[text, ImageSize -> Dynamic@size, 
    Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
    ScrollPosition -> Dynamic[{0, pos}, (pos = Last@#) &]];

(* triggers ONLY if text is changed! *)
trigger = makeTrigger[pane, text, (pos = pos + 1000; update[])];
pane = update[]; (* initialize pane *)
{With[{tr = trigger}, Dynamic[tr; pane, TrackedSymbols :> {text, pos}]], Dynamic@pos}
```

[image]

(The `"<"` character indicates the end of newly added content.)

First, a `trigger` is set up in the final line, that listens to whether `text` or `pos` is changed. If only `pos` is changed, then the resulting expression becomes `Dynamic[pane]`, updating the vertical scroll position as required. However, if `text` is changed, then `trigger` triggers and `update[]` kicks in, redrawing the whole `Pane` object from scratch, finding and setting the correct end-of-content position.

Now it became possibly to have various **controllers only updating independent variables** (like `text`, `pos`, etc.) and a **dependent expression that listens to the independent variables** and updates according to which of them was triggered.

Comment: +1, This is really cool! I do need this sort of functionality myself for some things, so chances are that I will be using your findings!

Comment: What did you use for the screen recording?

Comment: @Szabolcs I use Corel Capture to capture windows (I cannot capture parts of windows as video) to raw avi and then VirtualDub to export to animated gif.

Answer (score 6):

This is a somewhat hackish, but working possibility:

```
x = 2000!;

size = {200, 200};
Dynamic@Pane[x, ImageSize -> Dynamic[size], 
  Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
  ScrollPosition -> {0, 
    Dynamic[Last@
       Rasterize[
        Pane[x, ImageSize -> {size[[1]], Full}, 
         Scrollbars -> {False, True}], "RasterSize"] - size[[2]], 
     None]}]
```

Now try changing `x`:

```
x = 10!;
x = 100!;
x = 1000!;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

This solution will work even if the pane is resized using the resize grip (but that can be removed using `AppearanceElements` if needed).

The `None` in `Dynamic` was necessary to avoid the system trying to assign a value to `Rasterize`.

On Windows this scrolls 2 pixels below the lowest position, but this shouldn't cause any problems in practice.  ([On Windows `Pane` seems to have some rounding issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/768/how-to-work-around-column-cutting-off-a-pixel-row-from-images).)

Answer (score 3):

There is one obvious error in your code: `ScrollBars` should be `Scrollbars`.

---

You need to put `Dynamic` outside of `Pane` so that it is recalculated, and use a sufficiently large value to get to the bottom.  `1*^15` should do.

```
Print @ Dynamic @
  Pane[logText,
       Scrollbars -> {False, True},
       ImageSize -> {Full, 200},
       ScrollPosition -> {0, 1*^15}
  ];
```

Comment: @Szabolcs perhaps, but I did intend to complete it, which I have now done.  Besides, sometimes a tiny typo fix **is** the answer.

Comment: This does not work for me when all of `logText` fits in the `Pane`.  Can you fix that?

Comment: @Szabolcs can you give me an example?  I am using `logText = 
  StringJoin @@ 
   Table[ToString[i] <> "  this here is some text!\n", {i, 5}];` and it appears to work without problem.

Comment: I was using `logText = 10!` (tweak the number to get different lengths).  Admittedly, it is not a string ...  I can reproduce it with `logText = "boo"` as well, another version difference?

Comment: @Szabolcs his code specifies `ImageSize -> {Full,200}` therefore wouldn't that be a single line?

Comment: Same as with the OP: You can drop the `Print`

Comment: @Sjoerd I kept `Print` because I assumed it was part of the problem.  Sometimes it is the wrappers or context that result in a particular behavior; I felt it unwise to make assumptions and strip it.