# Alternative updating of a dynamic expression

Tags: dynamic

I am looking for a solution to selectively update a dynamic expression `expr` which is dependent on multiple control variables `{x, y, ...}`. I need to update `expr` differently (using `xUpdate` and `yUpdate`) according to which controller is manipulated, i.e. which control variable triggers an update, but without including update code in any of the controllers! That is, `Dynamic[expr]` itself has to include the different update modes.

**Question: Is there a method to update a dynamic expression differently depending on which parent-variable triggers an update?**

### 1. Include update in controller

The easy way would be to simply include the different update codes in the controllers, but as I said, this is not the desired way. The code is included here only for reference:

```
xUpdate[xin_, yin_] := {"x-trigger", yin + xin, yin};
yUpdate[xin_, yin_] := {"y-trigger", yin*10, yin};

x = y = 0; expr = yUpdate[x, y];
{Row@{"update x: ", 
   Slider[Dynamic[x, (x = #; expr = xUpdate[x, y]) &]]}, 
 Button["Update y", y = RandomReal[]; expr = yUpdate[x, y]]}
Dynamic[expr]
```

This works as expected, but in my use case I cannot update `expr` directly from the controllers. I have to do it in a way that is restricted to the last line, i.e. the `expr` itself has to do the updating according to which controller was manipulated.

### 2. Using `$ControlActiveSetting`

An alternative method is to rely on the global value of `$ControlActiveSetting`:

```
xUpdate[xin_, yin_] := {"x-trigger", yin + xin, yin};
yUpdate[xin_, yin_] := {"y-trigger", yin*10, yin};

x = y = 0;    
{Button["Update y", y = RandomReal[]], 
 Row@{"update x: ", Slider[Dynamic@x]}}
Dynamic[expr = If[$ControlActiveSetting, xUpdate[x, y], yUpdate[x, y]]; expr, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]
```

This correctly differentiates between the two update modes, but it incorrectly reverts to `y-trigger` whenever the x-slider is released. This is unwanted behaviour. A second problem with this is that `$ControlActiveSetting` cannot differentiate between multiple sliders (i.e. imagine a third `z` controller).

### 3. Intermediate solution a'la `$ControlActiveSetting`

A global flag (`trigger`, substituting `$ControlActiveSetting`) is set to either `"x"`, `"y"` or `"z"`, depending on which controller is being manipulated. This works as expected and can be extended to any number of controllers, but has the problem that I still have to set `trigger` in each controller, which I want to avoid.

```
xUpdate[xin_, yin_, zin_] := {"x-trigger", yin + xin, yin, zin};
yUpdate[xin_, yin_, zin_] := {"y-trigger", yin*10, yin, zin};
zUpdate[xin_, yin_, zin_] := {"z-trigger", zin*20, yin - 1, zin};

x = y = z = 0;
trigger = "x";    
{Button["Update y", trigger = "y"; y = RandomReal[]], 
 Row@{"update x: ", Slider[Dynamic[x, (trigger = "x"; x = #) &]]}, 
 Row@{"update z: ", Slider[Dynamic[z, (trigger = "z"; z = #) &]]}}
Dynamic[Switch[trigger, "x", xUpdate[x, y, z], "y", yUpdate[x, y, z], 
  "z", zUpdate[x, y, z]], TrackedSymbols :> {x, y, z}]
```

But it brings me closer to my real question:

**Question:**

**Is there a way to check globally which control variable is being actively manipulated/changed in the front-end?** Surely `Dynamic[expr]` knows about it as it has the `TrackedSymbols` option, but I cannot access this information from inside the `Dynamic`. I think of something like `CurrentValue["ManipulatedVariable"]` or `CurrentValue["ActualDynamicUpdatingTrigger"]` (which are nonexistent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way, which is probably not optimal, and also is kind of cheating, but. This is a generator for a "trigger":

```
ClearAll[makeTrigger]
SetAttributes[makeTrigger, HoldAll];
makeTrigger[res_, var_, updateCode_] :=
  Module[{varOld = var, trigger},
    trigger /; varOld =!= var := (
      varOld = var;
      res = updateCode
    );
    trigger];
```

now,

```
ClearAll[expr, x, y, z];
x = y = z = 0;
triggers = {
   makeTrigger[expr, x, xUpdate[x, y, z]],
   makeTrigger[expr, y, yUpdate[x, y, z]],
   makeTrigger[expr, z, zUpdate[x, y, z]]
};
```

and we can check, that this works:

```
{
  Button["Update y", y = RandomReal[]], 
  Row@{"update x: ", Slider[Dynamic[x]]}, 
  Row@{"update z: ", Slider[Dynamic[z]]}
}

With[{tr = triggers}, Dynamic[tr ; expr, TrackedSymbols :> {x, y, z}]]
```

Comment: This seems to be promising, as it approaches from a different angle. Why do you say it is not optimal? Because it does the `/;` checking for all three triggers at every update?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Well, it just seems a bit of a round-about method. There may be a more direct one which I am not aware of.

Comment: Though this is working marvellously in my use case (stay tuned), I really hope that there are other solutions, as I wan't to explore this particular field in total depth. So for the moment, I won't accept the answer, but wait a bit for others.

Comment: @István You don't have to explain your decisions regarding answer acceptance :-). Besides, I never thought of this answer as *the* solutiion, it feels more like a hack to me.

Comment: Yes, usually I don't explain, but here I got so excited thanks to you, that I had to write something!

Comment: Please see this [thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21671/89)!

Comment: This must be the saddest Q&A and accept with so low scores... :/ I find this functionality so useful, and I hardly can believe that there is no alternative (or even builtin) method to achieve this. Anyway, you got my accept!