# Making large tables easy to read with frozen headings and scrollbars

Tags: list-manipulation, front-end, output-formatting

I would like to represent a table containing a large amount of information in such a way that I can (a) use scrollbars and (b) have table headings that don't scroll off the screen [just like the Free Panes option in Excel].

```
headings = Table["Col" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, 10}];
data = Table[RandomReal[], {j, 1, 100}, {i, 1, 10}];
Pane[TableForm[Insert[data, headings, 1]], {400, 300}, Scrollbars -> True]
```

The code above gives me the scrollbars with an option to adjust the size of the viewing field, but it's not obvious to me how to make the headings stay on the screen.  (I'm ignoring rowheadings for the moment, to keep the problem simple, but I would like persistent row headings as well at some point.)

I'm not wedded to `Pane` or `TableForm` for that matter.  The key components that I'm looking for are an adjustable field size (manipulating the {400,300} in the above example), scrollbars and persistent headings.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3868/5

Comment: @rm-rf I agree.  There are some (relevant?) differences with (a) custom headings in this code and (b) decreased complexity due to not needing edit capabilities.  Not sure if that's enough to keep the question around.

Comment: I think you can add custom headings to those as well if you modify the right parts... For instance, F'x's answer produces A, B, C as the headings, which just need to be replaced with yours. Don't worry, the question won't be removed, but I'll explicitly mark it as a duplicate so that others can follow on for more complex and robust solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with based on the comments and suggestions posted:

```
cheadings = Table["Col" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, 10}];
rheadings = Table["Row" <> ToString[j], {j, 1, 100}];
data = Table[RandomReal[], {j, 1, 100}, {i, 1, 10}];
Dynamic@Pane[
  Grid[{
    {"", Pane[TableForm[Insert[data, cheadings, 1]], {500, 15}, 
      ScrollPosition -> {x, 0}], ""},
    {Pane[
      TableForm[Transpose@Insert[Transpose@data, rheadings, 1]], {50, 
       200}, ScrollPosition -> {0, y}],
     Pane[TableForm[data], {500, 200}, ScrollPosition -> {x, y}],
     VerticalSlider[Dynamic[y], {1400, 0, 5}, AutoAction -> True]},
    {"", Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 550, 5}, AutoAction -> True, 
      ImageSize -> 500], ""}
    }]
  ]
```

I've added row headings as well.  The size variables need to be tweaked manually for the size of the table.  Also, I don't know if this is machine dependent or not, but the response time of the Sliders improves dramatically if I set AutoAction -> True (which in the end adds a nice effect IMO).

Comment: This freeze my Mathematica 8.0 on Windows 7 for me

Comment: @liam good to know - I don't have M8 to test on so it would be good to know if others have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it was possible, but some work would be required to make it slick:

```
Pane[
 Column[{
   Pane[
    Grid[Insert[data, headings, 1],
     Background -> {None, {LightCyan}}],
    {800, 15}],
   Pane[
    Grid[data],
    {800, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: grid]

Comment: how about adding ItemSize->All to the Grid definitions. At least they are aligned...albeit do scroll with...

Comment: I hadn't thought of nested panes.  This solution handles the vertical scrollbar nicely but we lose the horizontal bar.  Grid doesn't seem to behave nicely with the scrollbars either.  I edited the answer with a possible next step.  The vertical scrollbar gets hidden, however.

Comment: @bobthechemist one idea could be to make the scrollposition of the first pane dynamic to let it update through the scrollposition of the second pane

Comment: @bobthechemist maybe this could help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1745/how-to-anchor-a-panes-scroll-position-to-the-bottom

Comment: @Stefan thanks - dynamic sliders do the trick.  I've got what I want based on input from this answer and its comments.  I don't know the proper Stackexchange etiquette; do I put the final version of my code in a comment and accept this answer?

Comment: @bobthechemist best is to add your own answer and accept it. Comments aren't regarded as permanent enough for answers. And you don't have to accept this answer (it was just a PoC)...!

Answer (score 1):

One day, WRI should get round to implementing and documenting the `TableView` function properly. It's frustratingly close to what you want:

```
TableView[data]
```

but its use isn't recommended (and the `TableHeadings` options are not implemented anyway).

[image: tableview]