# Generate a new output using Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, random

Thanks to methods found in the below, I was able to assemble those elements :

[Tile image on specific location without space between them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/752/tile-image-on-specific-location-without-space-between-them)

[How to combine images with the same dimensions in a grid?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246/how-to-combine-images-with-the-same-dimensions-in-a-grid)

[image]

Now, I would like to use Manipulate [] to have a button that, when pressed generate a new composition, "re-run" the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you actually need a Manipulate expression, or is this sufficient?

```
DynamicModule[{x = Null}, Column[{
   Button["Shuffle Images", 
    x = ImageAssemble[
      Partition[
       RandomSample[
        Flatten@{DarkBlueB, DarkBlueC, DarkBlueN, DarkBlueE}, 20], 5]]
    ],
   Dynamic[x]
}]]
```

Comment: this is so cool ! Later I will add sophistications but for now tho is real good !

Comment: How can I adjust the width of both items ? I tried to use ItemSize in the column but it does not work. The ImageAssemble appear smaller than it should for now.

Comment: @500 please try `Image[ImageAssemble[ ... ], Magnification -> 1]`